# Are there any symmetries in the Mixmaster model?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, chaos-theory

The [Mixmaster model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixmaster_universe) is usually presented as one example of chaotic models in physics and cosmology.

Usually, "chaos" or "randomness" may be related to a complete lack of symmetries and laws of physics. Since this model is chaotic, does it have any symmetries?

Comment: These models may have “hidden” symmetries. See e.g. [this Living Review](https://doi.org/10.12942/lrr-2008-1).

Comment: @A.V.S. does this mean that there are mixmaster models with a completely lack of symmetries and others with some hidden symmetries? Can you think of a mixmaster model with no symmetries at all?